# CiviMail Sent/Scheduled Mailings does not list mailings for some users

Tags: civimail, permissions, acl

I'm in a context using some CiviCRM ACLs to restrict access for regional staff to regional contacts. Some core staff have access across the regions.

However, the regional staff cannot view the list of sent mailings.

After some code investigation, it seems that CiviMail will only show people mailings that have been made with some sort of reference to one of the groups that defines contacts the user has access to view or edit.

This is pretty restrictive because it means mailings have to be sent to an ACL group (and therefore that ACL groups must be mailing groups).

In reality, a country-wide email newsletter is sent, but the regional staff cannot see these. Also, regional staff can't see draft mailings that they have created to other mailing groups.

I'm on CiviCRM 5.10.3 (and Drupal, if it matters)

Has anyone found a solution? I'd like them to be able to see all mailings, and certainly mailings they create themselves (which will be to contacts they have access to).